Can I say 'I suggest her to go to the doctor's'?
Correct usage and why is is this grammatically incorrect?

Welcome! Please edit to say a bit more about which part of this sentence concerns you and what your concerns are. This will give answers that can help you more personally. I suspect the concern is about the object of "suggest" being the recipient of the suggestion, but I shouldn't assume.

@user1176409 - If to the doctor's puzzles you, see this.

advise her to go but suggest she goes.

Collins Dictionary illustrates the use of suggest in sense 1B1:

I suggest you ask him some specific questions about his past. [VERB that] [emphasis added]


I suggested to Mike that we go out for a meal with his colleagues. [VERB + to][emphasis added]

The OP’s example

I suggest her to go to the doctor's.

needs to either add a to

I suggest [to] her to go to the doctor's.

or adopt the declarative content clause:

I suggest [(that) she goes] to the doctor's.

The complementiser can be omitted, as what the first example from Collins has done.
Longman after sense 7 has more usage notes:

In everyday English, you suggest that someone does something:


I suggest that she waits a few weeks.


✗Don’t say: I suggest her to wait a few weeks.

The above is similar to the OP's example.

• In more formal English, you suggest that someone do something, using the base form of the verb (=the infinitive without ‘to’):


I suggest that she wait a few weeks.

We could also adopt the last usage for the OP’s example:

I suggest [(that) she go] to the doctor's.


If would use italics instead of brackets, as brackets suggest a possibility.

Thanks, @Lambie.  We are probably following different style guides.  Let me get some links and we can compare.  Goodnight.
